# what will be the select query for excluding empty values in ms access

Tags: ms-access, select-query

I am trying

```
select * from table where Contact Is Not null
```

but it is displaying values including empty values

Comment: Could you please update your question that you are looking for query which will exclude the empty strings also along with null values.

Comment: why you have down voted. Now i have changed null to empty @panther

Comment: I have downvoted previously, now when you have corrected . I am upvoting again

Comment: You haven't upvoted @Panther

Comment: I did and However , I am not oblighed to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is correct but probably you have zero length strings in your Contact column. You can use

```
select * from table where len(Nz(Contact, '')) > 0
```

The `Nz` function returns the specified default value if the column is null.

Comment: @Vampire I would recommend taking a read through http://allenbrowne.com/vba-NothingEmpty.html it was a great read to learn more about Null's, Nothing's, and Empty strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
select * from table where Len([Contact] & "")>0
```

Comment: This query displaying null values.. I want to display not null values

Comment: @Vampire:- Updated my answer. Please check now!

Comment: displaying same result (null values).

Comment: @Vampire:- Then there is a very much possibility that your column has empty strings with which you are getting confused and hence getting the empty values which you think is NULL

Comment: The length must be greater than 0. You can than loose the `Is Not Null` check because `null & ""` will always return `""`.